# Is there matrix version of Riemann sum approximation?

Tags: matrix-calculus, riemann-sum

Is there any Riemann sum approximation for $\int_{A}^{B} tr(X^{-1} dX)$? Here $A, B$ are PSD matrices and $B \succ A$.

I'm thinking of $\sum_{t=1}^T tr\left(X(t)^{-1} (X(t) - X(t-1))\right)$, but how do I choose $X(t)$ in order to guarantee the error decays as $O(1/T)$? If I choose $X(t) \succ X(t-1)$ and $\|X(t) - X(t-1)\|_2 \sim \frac{1}{T}$, would the approximation error decays with the rate $O(1/T)$?

Comment: It's now solved. I forgot to mention in the question, $\int_A^B tr(X^{-1} dX) = \int_A^B d \log |X|$ (as also pointed out by @greg below). Importantly, I can choose whatever path for the integral as it is independent of the specific path, so I can choose the continuous path across all $X(t)$. By standard argument of Riemann sum approximation, the error would roughly be $\sum_{t=1}^T \|X(t) - X(t-1)\|_2^2$, which is $O(1/T)$ if $\|X(t) - X(t-1)\|_2 = O(1/T)$.

Answer (score 2):

By Jacobi's formula
$$\eqalign{
{\rm Tr}(X^{-1}dX)
 &= d\,{\rm Tr}(\log(X)) \\
 &= d\log(\det(X)) \\
}$$
Therefore the integral can be evaluated *exactly* without needing approximations
$$\eqalign{
{\cal J} &= \int d\log(\det(X)) \\
 &= \log(\det(B)) - \log(\det(A)) \\
 &= \log(\det(BA^{-1})) \\
}$$

Comment: I was indeed aware of this exact integral. I was analyzing an algorithm approximating this integral with Riemann sum and try to get the error bound. But anyway, thank you for the answer!!!